# Sequelize - self references has many relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with Mysql.

I have a table:

> ***Items***

that contain the fields:

> ***{Id,Name,Price}***

I want to made a self relation within the Item to himself.
The target to be able to do Item.subItems and to get a list of all the sub items that belong to this item.

and please show me how to include the new model in

> ***include:[{model:SubItem}]... when i fetch the a query.***

I have tried many option of relations:

> ***Item.hasMany(Item,{ through: SubItem,as:'subItems'});***
>
> ***Item.hasMany(Item);***

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 25):

To create the self reference

```
Item.hasMany(Item, {as: 'Subitems'})
```

To find subitems using include

```
Item.find({where:{name: "Coffee"},include:[{model: Item, as: 'Subitems'}]})
```

See the Sample code below,

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
, sequelize = new Sequelize("test", "root", "root", {logging: false})
, Item    = sequelize.define('Item', { name: Sequelize.STRING })

Item.hasMany(Item, {as: 'Subitems'})


var chainer = new Sequelize.Utils.QueryChainer
, item  = Item.build({ name: 'Coffee' })
, subitem1 = Item.build({ name: 'Flat White' })
, subitem2 = Item.build({ name: 'Latte' })


sequelize.sync({force:true}).on('success', function() {
  chainer
    .add(item.save())
    .add(subitem1.save())
    .add(subitem2.save())

  chainer.run().on('success', function() {
    item.setSubitems([subitem1, subitem2]).on('success', function() { 

    /*  One way 
      item.getSubitems().on('success', function(subitems) {
        console.log("subitems: " + subitems.map(function(subitem) { 
          return subitem.name 
        }))
      })
    */

    //The include way you asked
    Item.find({where:{name: "Coffee"},include:[{model: Item, as: 'Subitems'}]}).success(function(item) {
         console.log("item:" + JSON.stringify(item));
    })

  })
}).on('failure', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
})
```

And the log data is below:

item:{"id":1,"name":"Coffee","createdAt":"2014-08-05T06:25:47.000Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-05T06:25:47.000Z","ItemId":null,"subitems":[{"id":2,"name":"Flat White","createdAt":"2014-08-05T06:25:47.000Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-05T06:25:47.000Z","ItemId":1},{"id":3,"name":"Latte","createdAt":"2014-08-05T06:25:47.000Z","updatedAt":"2014-08-05T06:25:47.000Z","ItemId":1}]}

Comment: Hi - even though this answer is quite old - can you eventually also elaborate on the required migration/database schema?

Comment: @siyang what if i have more than one "subitems" (Like "Subitem1", "Subitem2") ? In my case i have "Subject" model and i want to store it's successor's Id and predecessor's Id.

Comment: Where is setSubitems coming from?